# MDX is not giving correct result

Tags: ssas

Could you please to get rid of the wrong unwanted outcome in SSAS cube. The issue is the measure is giving result when is select only one bottler in the filter and if i select multiple bottlers which is giving whole country measure values.

P.S. Please do not reject the question if i did not framed correctly as its very important for me.

[image]

Comment: You should include example data, expected/desired results, actual results, and a clear explanation of why the current results are wrong. I'm not well-versed in SSAS but nonetheless get the impression this is currently a very vague question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that MDX to:

```
SUM(EXISTING Crossjoin(...
```